# SDL2 & C++ - Load an image as a pixel array

Tags: c++, pixel, sdl-2

So, I've tried searching online, but I didn't really find what I need.

Is there a way, in SDL2, to get an array of pixels from an image? ...after I get the array, I don't care anymore about the previous structure (SDL_Texture, SDL_Image, SDL_Surface, and so on) I just need the pixel array...how can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lock the surface that you get by loading the image, access the pixel data through the surface's `pixels` member, then unlock the surface?

Comment: it works but, isn't this slow? I need to access the pixels many times, and I really need just the values...couldn't I copy the `pixels` member, so I can then free the surface and not bother with locking/unlocking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load image as surface and get data from `void *pixels;` (it's member of SDL_Surface).